# Reading data from an irregular text file to a class in C++

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, text-files, file-handling

I've been working on a project which requires me to read student data from a text file to a non-STL data structure. It has data like this:

```
semester 1                                                              
Code    Course Title    Crd Pnt Grd Rmk  <----(This line is of no use to me :/)                             

                                         <----(This line is of no use to me :/)

code1   course1 1   3.33    B+                                          
code2   course2 3   3   B       

code3   course3 3   3   B                                           

semester2

Code    Course Title    Crd Pnt Grd Rmk

code1   course1 1   3.33    B+                                          



code2   course2 3   3   B
```

Now as you can see, the text file has some irregular endline characters (\n) and spaces as well as the data that i do not need (notice the lines that i do not need). So far I have made a course class to store data of a single course. Then a semester class with array of courses and SGPA and then a student class with an array of semesters and CGPA. I am using arrays as I'm not allowed to use STL. I know array may waste some storage but using anything else like making my custom list class would prove much slower. I have data for more than 200 students and each one has studied 3 to 7 semesters with number of courses varying between 5 to 7 per semester. As an exercise, I cannot use STL or other built-in libraries except the c++ string library. I have tried to use getline to pick a single line and then used some conditions to check whether it is a course. But it does not work as intended. Secondly I am unable to figure out how to ignore lines that I do not need (like empty spaces and the headers for course name etc) How can I tackle such irregular text file for data manipulation? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest regular expressions. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: Let me edit the question

Comment: It's very easy to "tackle such irregular text file" - just write the code to do it. Your question must be either: "I cannot figure out a logical algorithm to do this"; or "I know what the logical algorithm is, but I am unable to translate it to C++". In the former case, this has nothing to do with C++. The logic is the same, whether coded in C++, Java, Perl, Python, or anything else. In the latter case, you need to edit the question and show what work you have already done, and explain what's missing, and which parts you cannot figure out how to translate to C++.

Comment: Thanks for telling me where I'm wrong in asking the question. I've made an edit to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've done parsing the text file :) I picked the text line by line and using `string::find` and `string::substr`, the job became much easier. Thanks for your suggestion on my question @Sam.